# Spring Boot Json deserialization with slashes

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, backslash

In a Spring boot 2.2.X app, I have a rest endpoint that accepts any simple Json object. The java type used to accommodate this is `Map<String,Object>`.

Example input:

```
{
   "productId":123,
   "type": Perishable
   "location":"\\server\path\to\images\123.png"
}
```

I'm facing unexpected behavior with the image file location String. In my controller, when I inspect the contents of the `Map<String,Object>` I see the following value. Some slashes are stripped, and some aren't. (I used a custom mapper to allow slashes at all places in json -> JsonParser.Feature "allow_backslash_escaping_any_character").

```
@PostMapping(value = "products}")
public UUID persistProduct(@RequestBody @NotNull Map<String,Object> parameters){
    return this.productService.persistProduct(parameters);
}
```

[image: Controller after deserialization]

Note that the first two backslashes are rendered as one, but it's actually still two backslashes. My app now deserialized this Map back to a json string, to persist it in the database. This is done by using standard Jackson classes:

```
public static String toJsonString(Object o){
    try{
        return new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()).writer().writeValueAsString(o);
    }
    catch (JsonProcessingException e){
        throw new UncheckedWrapperException("Converting an object to a JSON literal string", e);
    }
}
```

Once persisted to the database the entire Json becomes:

[image]

If I now change the input by consistently escaping every backslash character with another backslash:

```
{
   "productId":123,
   "type": Perishable
   "location":"\\\\server\\path\\to\\images\\123.png"
}
```

The result in the controller looks promising, but the database record now contains ALL slashes (so the escaping suddenly has no effect, which means to many slashes are stored?)

[image: controller]

[image: database]

I don't really understand this behavior. Is there a way to tell Spring or Jackson to store in the database EXACTLY what is being entered in the input json? I obviously would also like to avoid jeopardizing the endpoint's security by simply disabling this.

Comment: Hey! Can you show a bit of the code? Would be extremely helpful. The controller and the way you serialize would be nice!

Comment: @Jason The controller is very straigthforward; I added it to the question. The deserialization feature to allow backslashes was added using a property in the property file. The serialization to the database uses standard Jackson: `new ObjectMapper().writer().writeValueAsString(o)` (where o is the Map<String,Object> from my controller).

Comment: Using backslashes will cause you all sorts of headaches. Why not use slashes? As long as you use Java API to access the resources you should be fine, also on a windows system.

Comment: @Ralf Well, I didn't want to enforce Java's quirkyness to the clients of this API but obviously a working application is more important so I'll look into validating that the location value doesn't contain backslashes so I can warn the client that they should use forward slashes.

Comment: @user1884155, I guess what's quirky depends on the point of view... Windows is the only OS (I am aware of) to use backslashes to separate path elements.

Comment: there is an annotation @JsonRawValue that might help you. Anyway the double backslash I think will be unescaped, so you will need to send something like this in your input "\\\\server\path\to\images\123.png" to achieve the desired result: "\\server\path\to\images\123.png"